# Is there a way to show the actual Attachment links inside the list view for my custom list

Tags: list, development, list-view, attachments, quick-edit

I have added a custom list inside my sharepoint 2013. and i chose to attach a file inside my list item from "Edit Tab">>"Attach File". but when i chose to display the "Attachment" field inside my list view , i will get the following symbol:-

[image]

instead of the actual attachment link/s??
so is there a way to fix this ?

**EDIT** now based on @Gautam reply, i tried this JSLINK , and it worked :-

```
(function () {  

    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>')); 

    var linkFieldContext = {};

    linkFieldContext.Templates = {};

    linkFieldContext.Templates.Fields = {

        "Attachments": { "View": AttachmentsFieldTemplate }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(linkFieldContext);

})();



function AttachmentsFieldTemplate(ctx) {
    var listItemId = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
    var listName = ctx.ListTitle;       
    return getAttachments(listName, listItemId);
}

function getAttachments(listName,listItemId) {

    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var webServiceUrl = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")/AttachmentFiles";
    var attachHtml = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: webServiceUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                attachHtml += "<a href='" + data.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl + "'>" + data.d.results[i].FileName + "</a>";
                if (i != data.d.results.length - 1) {
                    attachHtml += "<br/>";
                }                
            }          
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    return attachHtml;
}
```

but the problem i am facing is that when i click on the list view i will get the following error for a couple of seconds, then the page will refresh automatically and show the attachments correctly:-
[image]

so is there a way to overcome this temporary error message which is being displayed??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1** - not sure why its showing error, works at my end. Could be something to do with jquery loading issue.

You can the below `jsLink` to show the attachments:

```
(function () {  

    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>')); 

    var linkFieldContext = {};

    linkFieldContext.Templates = {};

    linkFieldContext.Templates.Fields = {

        "Attachments": { "View": AttachmentsFieldTemplate }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(linkFieldContext);

})();



function AttachmentsFieldTemplate(ctx) {
    var listItemId = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
    var listName = ctx.ListTitle;       
    return getAttachments(listName, listItemId);
}

function getAttachments(listName,listItemId) {

    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var webServiceUrl = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")/AttachmentFiles";
    var attachHtml = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: webServiceUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                attachHtml += "<a href='" + data.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl + "'>" + data.d.results[i].FileName + "</a>";
                if (i != data.d.results.length - 1) {
                    attachHtml += "<br/>";
                }                
            }          
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    return attachHtml;
}
```

**Option 2** - using pure javascript ajax calls, you can use the below code as well :

```
(function () {  

    var linkFieldContext = {};

    linkFieldContext.Templates = {};

    linkFieldContext.Templates.Fields = {

        "Attachments": { "View": AttachmentsFieldTemplate }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(linkFieldContext);

})();



function AttachmentsFieldTemplate(ctx) {
    var listItemId = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
    var listName = ctx.ListTitle;       
    return getAttachments(listName, listItemId);
}

function getAttachments(listName,listItemId) {

    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var webServiceUrl = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")/AttachmentFiles";
    var attachHtml = "";

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', webServiceUrl , false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('accept','application/json;odata=verbose');
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                for(var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                    attachHtml += "<a href='" + data.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl + "'>" + data.d.results[i].FileName + "</a>";
                    if (i != data.d.results.length - 1) {
                        attachHtml += "<br/>";
                    }                
                }               
             }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send(null);   

    return attachHtml;
}
```

Once you attach the jslink to the list, it shows the file name (see below screenshot):

[image]

Reference - [Show Attachments with JSLink](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/29f7998f-ffc5-4877-b975-a49631b53ba2/show-attachments-with-jslink?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: can you check my edit,,now you jslink will work ,, but i am getting an error when the list view first loads...

Comment: have updated the answer, please check with the 2nd option. Regarding issue with first option, looks like issue with jquery loading/conflicting, can't really say for sure why its happening.

Comment: now the second script (pure javascript) will not show any temporary errors.. but it will wok for one time only.. and i need to keep doing full refresh to the web page to get it working well..could this problem related to the Minimum download strategy which is enabled on the site ?

Comment: hmm MDS is causing the issue. Can you try to disable and check ?

Comment: but is there any drawback if i disable this feature? or i can enable/disable it for testing without any drawbacks ??

Comment: there no drawback to disabling this feature. You can enable/disable it anytime you want without any issue. At my end, i always disable this feature as it  interferes with my scripts loading. If you have publishing feature turned on, then you should always keep it disabled. Even if publishing feature is not turned on, IMO you should disable MDS.

Comment: now i kept the MDS feature enabled... but i modify the script to use `RegisterModuleInit()` which allow the script to fire every-time i navigate to the view.. but i have noted one drawback of using this script in general, is that the list navigation become somehow slow... i think this is a side effect which i have to live with... as the script will try to search for any attachment per item.. is this correct ?? and i am showing 30 items per page..

Comment: Yes that correct, it will make one ajax call per list item, which means 30 rest api calls for the view.

Comment: so this gives and indication why sharepoint does not provide this capability out of the box :) so is there a way to improve it ? so it do one call instead of 30 calls per page ?

Comment: Looks like Microsoft has dropped the ball here :) , cant think of a better way, would have added it in the answer if i could ;) , here 30 REST calls are necessary unfortunately. In case of a custom webpart, we can get it in one REST call but not in OOTB list.